# Programmatically/script to run zsh command

Tags: shell, zsh

As part of a bigger script I'm using `print -z ls` to have zsh's input buffer show the `ls` command. This requires me to manually press enter to actually execute the command. Is there a way to have ZSH execute the command?

To clarify, the objective is to have a command run, keep it in history, and in case another command is running it shouldn't run in parallel or something like that.

Comment: Why do you want to put a command into the input edit buffer, if you then don't want to give the user a chance to actually edit it?

Comment: The script will be triggered externally, so do not wish manual interaction. However, I also don't wish 2 commands to run at the same time, and prefer to have the history reflect the exact things run.

Comment: @user1934428 In case you're interested in the solution, and the purpose, check my answer and the gist: https://gist.github.com/alexmipego/89c59a5e3abe34faeaee0b07b23b56eb

Comment: Interesting idea ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I've found is:

```
python -c "import fcntl, sys, termios; fcntl.ioctl(sys.stdin, termios.TIOCSTI, '\n');
```

I'm not sure why, but sometimes you might need to *repeat* the command 2 times for the actual command to be executed. In my case this is happening because I send a process to the background, although this still doesn't make much sense because that process is sending a signal back to the original shell (triggering a trap) which actually calls this code.

In case anyone is interested, this was my goal:
https://gist.github.com/alexmipego/89c59a5e3abe34faeaee0b07b23b56eb

Comment: This solution works for me. However, it prints an additional new line before the next command when I use it in a function like this: `print -z cd /home && python -c ...`